# typescript: how to export function and interfaces

Tags: typescript, import, typescript-typings

I need a basic example about how to export functions and associated types (interfaces) in typescript.

For example, I have the following readConfig function that returns an IConfig, and I'd like to know how to put that function and interface into a separate config.ts file, and then import it.

```
interface IConfig {
  db: string,
  table: string,
  connstring: string,
  sources: Array<{
    db: string,
    connstring: string
  }>
}

import { safeLoad } from 'js-yaml';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const config: IConfig = readConfig();

// [do stuff with config]


function readConfig(configFile: string = 'configuration.yml'): IConfig {
  const config: IConfig = safeLoad(readFileSync(configFile, 'utf8'));
  return config;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**some-file.ts**

```
export interface IConfig {
  db: string,
  table: string,
  connstring: string,
  sources: Array<{
    db: string,
    connstring: string
  }>
}

export function readConfig(configFile: string = 'configuration.yml'): IConfig {
  const config: IConfig = safeLoad(readFileSync(configFile, 'utf8'));
  return config;
}
```

**some-other-file.ts**

```
import { safeLoad } from 'js-yaml';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { IConfig, readConfig} from 'some-file'

const config: IConfig = readConfig();

// [do stuff with config]
```